# Can anyone help me with code below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to code an application that, for example teachers, can use to check students reading ages. There is a part where it asks the user to input how many keywords they want which is what I'm currently confused / stuck on.

My code:

```
counter = 0

amount_keywords = []

input_keywords = int(input("Enter Number Of Keywords:"))

while(counter != input_keywords):

input_keywords = str(input("Enter Keyword:"))

amount_keywords.append(input_keywords)

counter = counter + 1
```

Whats happening is If I put 0 onto the integer "Enter Number Of Keywords:" it works fine and passes the next section asking to put keywords in, which is perfect and working right. But if I put for example the number 3 it should come up with the string "Enter Keyword:" three times because that's what I've put into the integer but instead out carries on going. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Could you correct the indentation of the code?

Answer (score 2):

You have used the variable input_keywords to hold the number of keywords to input but then you redefine it, inside the while loop, to hold each keyword. Thus, if you enter 3 before the loop, then type the keyword 'a' during the loop, now input_keywords = 'a' so when the while loop compares this to counter, they will never be equal, so it keeps going. Try naming things more clearly and don't reuse variables for different purposes. For example:

```
counter = 0
amount_keywords = []
n_keywords = int(input("Enter Number Of Keywords:"))
while(counter != n_keywords):
    keyword = str(input("Enter Keyword:"))
    amount_keywords.append(keyword)
    counter = counter + 1
```

To debug things like this yourself, add a print statement in the while loop to see the value of counter and input_keywords and see why the loop-ending condition is not being met. Or use a debugger that lets you step through the code and look at variable values.